# HTML5 Canvas Eraser Tool

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have a shape drawer tool in my project. I can draw polygons just by writing something like this:

```
      for (var j = 0; j < polygon.points.length - 1; j++) {
        // for example if points.length is 11, we do
        // up to j = 9 so j + 1 = 10 which is last index
        ctx.lineTo(polygon.points[j + 1].x, polygon.points[j + 1].y)
      }
```

This is working great. However now I would like to add an "eraser tool", where the user can delete parts of the polygon with the mouse. However I'm having a hard time knowing how to regenerate the new polygon points after the eraser tool was used.

Just to explain myself better here's an example of another software eraser tool:

[image]

After some erasing

[image]

Note that I'm more interested in the actual polygon points (the x,y coordinates). And I usually assume there are no curved lines, so each polygon point is connected via a straight line. So if in the above image there are some curves thanks to my poor mouse abilities, in theory the end result should always be a polygon with straigh lines.

Is there any known tools, math or anything else that can help me achieve this?

Comment: @Calculuswhiz thanks for your answer! The main reason Im concerned about the points is because I want to be able to recreate the polygon after closing the app. Also in the context of hiding/showing the different existing shapes.

Comment: No, I would say I want more to generate the polygon points after a free mouse drawing. Think of it like a semantic segmentation of an image

Comment: Search "Boolean operations on polygons javascript"

Comment: you are mixing two concepts into images. when saving the points of the polygon, you are working with the vector image. when you delete with the mouse, you are working on rendering. if your background is white, you can associate a brush image overlay and save the x and y positions.

Comment: It is possible to convert the polygon to bitmap (as you already do) erase pixels and then convert back to a vector (polygon). However to do that is very complex and well beyond the space given for an answer. Not only does the original polygons stay intact where unaffected by erase, but the erase can create holes (new polygons), and very complex edges. The new edges and holes must be optimized and fitted to lines and curves to match the erased parts, if not the resulting polygons will require thousands of points making them very slow to render.